# Method to OR the CSS class ends with selector?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS class selector which will select all `<td>` children of even `<tr>` children of `<tbody>` where `<tr>` belongs to any class ending in 2:

```
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='2'] > td{
           background-color: #FFF7C7;
}
```

What I would like to do is select all `<td>` children of even `<tr>` children of `<tbody>` where `<tr>` belongs to any class ending in an even number up to but not including 10. I hoped I could do something to the effect of:

```
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$=('2' || '4' || '6' || '8')] > td{
           background-color: #FFF7C7;
}
```

So my question is, how do I implement an OR case in the class ends with selector?

For reference here is a sample of the HTML (I would like to select all `<td>` of the first two rows.):

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="ctgry_2"><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
  <tr class="ctgry_6"><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
  <tr class="ctgry_3"><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: That's not possible with CSS, try something like LESS or [SASS](http://http://sass-lang.com).

Comment: @s1h4d0w, to say it's not possible with CSS and then suggest using LESS or Sass ignores the fact that LESS and Sass generate CSS, which would mean that it **is** possible. It's just that it's verbose.

Comment: don't operate with classes through attribute selectors `[class...]` `[class$=2]` is not `has class ended with 2`, it's just `class attribute ended with 2`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The feature he is asking for just can't be used in CSS. With SASS or LESS he could achieve what he wants.

Comment: Class names was never designed to be subject of css selectors in any context except `.className`. Why can't to add `even`/`odd`- like classes?

Answer (score 1):

With CSS you'd need to use `,` to separate each individual selector:

```
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='0'] > td,
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='2'] > td,
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='4'] > td,
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='6'] > td,
.table-striped > tbody >  tr:nth-child(2n)[class$='8'] > td
```

This is quite verbose, and should be immediately apparent that you're probably making a poor selector choice, where you could just use classes on the appropriate elements.

Comment: beat me for a second ;)